# Difference between analytical cookies in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

Sorry if this has been done to death my stackoverflow-fu may have failed me, and Google hasn't been much help either.

I'm just looking for a high level explanation of the differences between the two Sitecore cookies:

SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE
SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE

I'm interested what types of information stored against them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Sitecore CMS 6.5 & DMS 2.0 Engagement Analytics Configuration Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/engagement_analytics_configuration_reference_sc65-usletter.pdf)

`SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE`: To identify repeat visits from a single user, Sitecore sends a persistent session cookie to the web client. The name of the persistent session cookie is SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE. The persistent session cookie expires one year after the last page requested from the solution by the web client.

`SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE`: To identify a sequence of HTTP requests from a single user, Sitecore sends an Engagement Analytics session cookie to the web client. The name of the session cookie is SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE. The value of the analytics session cookie before the first pipe character ("|") matches a value in the VisitId column of the Visits table to identify an analytics visit record in the Analytics database. This cookie expires when the user closes the Web client.

Comment: Little more info as well: If you install FireFox Web Developer extension you can view the information about the cookies (what's stored in them, when they expire etc). For instance, from the top of my head, the ASP.NET Session ID will be used to identify the user for the SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE.

Comment: @Trayek agree, but you don't need any extensions for Firefox. Just open `Options` menu, select `Privacy` and `Remove individual cookies` - you can preview all cookies and their value there.

Comment: Thanks for you help guys.  The reference guide link is exactly what I needed; perhaps I wasn't paying enough attention whilst I was scanning the Sitecore site, stackoverflow can make you lazy! :D

Comment: I don't see a Session cookie anymore (Sitecore 8), only the Global one.